# Не работает bluetooth socket (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, bluetooth

У меня есть код, который я взял из видео:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
server.bind(("8c:88:2b:20:15:8d", 4))
server.listen(1)
client, addr = server.accept()

try:
    print("Server started")
    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print(f"Message: {data.decode('utf-8')}")
        message = input("Enter message: ")
        client.send(messge.encode('utf-8'))
except OSError as e:
    pass

client.close()
server.close()
```

Но дело в том, что весь код, начиная на строчке `client, addr = server.accept()` попросту игнорируется, пробовал через Thread, но даже тогда значение client не задавалось, код просто виснет. Заранее спасибо за помощь.